# SQL query to return specific data

Tags: sql, regex, confluence

Data:

```
https://example.com/display/~EET/Norton+Core+Forum+Support">https:/example.com/display/EET/Norton+Core+Forum+Support</
```

Requirement Output:

```
https://example.com/display/EET
```

Constant:

```
https://example.com/display/
```

Currently using SQL with:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR (body_data, '(https://example.com/display/\S*\")') AS returnex
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has updated his information of sample so adding following solution now. Considering that your actual Input is like shown samples only.

```
(?<=>)(http|https):[^<]*
```

[Regex Demo:](https://regex101.com/r/mxoBFu/8)

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
https:[^<]*
```

OR to match both http or https try:

```
(http|https):[^<]*
```

[Regex Demo:](https://regex101.com/r/mxoBFu/7)

Comment: thanks, but that won't suit for data like(new updated in question)

Comment: @AnnadatePiyush, could you please check my EDIT solution and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
(https:[^~]+)(?=~)(.*)
```

replace with $1. Demo

https://regex101.com/r/G1qVEN/2/